# No option to import documents into Google Docs

Tags: google-drive

How do I import document into Google Docs?  I don't see an import option.  Do I open the drive and drop it in?

I am trying to [follow these ACRA](http://code.google.com/p/acra/wiki/BasicSetup) (Application Crash Report for Android) steps:

1. Login to your Google Docs account
2. Import the CrashReports-template.csv contained in the archive (acra-4.2.3/CrashReport/doc), with conversion enabled
3. Open the imported document
4. Rename it as you like
5. In the Google Docs menu, click on Tools / Form / Create a form

Where is this Google Docs Menu tools/Form/Create its not on drive an logging in on the web to google docs, I don't see it.

Where is import option and conversion enabled?  I have Google Docs and I'm on a Mac.

Answer (score 4):

When you navigate to Google Docs, there should be a button to the right of create with a picture of a drive. Click it and select Files or folder. You can navigate to the file and should be able to import it fine. A message should also appear with upload settings that you may specify.